# can we convert value type to referance type in c# or .net supported language

Tags: c#

hi  can we convert value type to referance type in c# or .net supported language 
like int is value type ...so can we convert it referance type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the subject called boxing and unboxing.

```
int i = 5;
object o = i;
int j = (int)o;
```

etc.

Answer (score 10):

For what purpose?

```
object intAsRef = 32;
```

is an int as a reference type. But this is called boxing ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx)) and is generally considered to be something to avoid rather than craved.

On the other hand, if you want to *pass* a value object by reference so that you can alter its value inside a method then you need to change the signature of the receiving method and the call:

```
public void ChangeValueOfInt(ref int input)
{
    input = 4;
}

int a = 2;
ChangeValueOfInt(ref a);
//a now equals 4
```

Comment: If you want to change the value in a lambda expression where `ref` parameter is not allowed,then you'd have to use boxing.

Answer (score 2):

Any value type can be converted to reference type, for example:

```
int myInt = 5;
object obj = myInt;
```

Comment: But bear in mind that this is _not_ equivalent to the C construct `int* obj = &myInt`.  The boxed reference is a _copy_ of the value, so you cannot mutate the original, whereas a C reference actually points to the memory address of the local and could allow mutation of the original.  It could also allow your application to blow up if you pass a pointer to a value on the stack that gets persisted and used after the calling method exits.  For that last reason (among others), .NET disallows capturing a reference to a value type and _persisting_ it.

Answer (score 1):

The process is called "boxing" in .NET, it refers to the fact that even value types inherit the reference type `Object`.  Any type in .NET can be cast to `Object` thusly:

```
int myint = 0;
object myIntAsRefType = myInt;
```

You can do this with other reference types, as well:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
object rndAsObject = rnd;
```

Before you can use any of their own methods or properties, you must un-box them:

```
if(myIntAsRefType is int)
int myNewInt = myIntAsRefType as int;
```

Alternatively:

```
if(myIntAsRefType is int)
int myNewInt = (int)myIntAsRefType;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Boxing and UnBoxing you can convert any value type to reference type. Boxing would allow you to wrap your value type around Object and UnBoxing does the opposite.

Boxing

```
int i = 10;
Object obj = (Object)i;
```

UnBoxing

```
int j=(int)obj;
```